# Installing Skype in Manjaro

Tags: package-management, pacman, manjaro, skype

I'm having some problems installing the skype package on linux Manjaro using the pacman command since I get the following error:

```
sudo pacman -S skype
error: target not found: skype
```

I made sure that I have multilib in /etc/pacman.conf enabled as you can see :

```
[multilib]
SigLevel = PackageRequired
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
```

I updated the mirrors with `sudo pacman -Syyu` and got:

```
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core                                                 138,9 KiB  3,77M/s 00:00 [#############################################] 100%
 extra                                               1922,3 KiB  3,50M/s 00:01 [#############################################] 100%
 community                                              4,0 MiB  3,47M/s 00:01 [#############################################] 100%
 multilib                                             188,4 KiB  4,28M/s 00:00 [#############################################] 100%
:: Starting full system upgrade...
 there is nothing to do
```

and I still cannot find this package.

What should I do to solve this problem ?

Comment: No idea how Manjaro works, but in Arch Skype is in the AUR...

Comment: Note that there is also the upcoming Skype alpha, basically redone from scratch. At https://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/installing-skype-for-linux-alpha-on-arch-linux/td-p/4434584 is a guide on how to install it on Arch and such.

Comment: @phk I'm going to side with [this guy](https://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Skype-for-Linux-Alpha-and-calling-on-Chrome-amp-Chromebooks/m-p/4434313#M14696) on that one. If you need a web browser, Chrome and Firefox will allow you to browse more than just `web.skype.com`. The previous Skype version is available in the [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/skype), or in its "dynamic" version [over at skype.com](https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/).

Answer (score 5):

Skype is not in the Manjaro package repositories, but it is in [Arch Linux's AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/) or "Arch User Repository". As it says on the AUR website, "AUR packages are user produced content. Any use of the provided files is at your own risk."

On my Manjaro Linux 17.1 machine, I used the following steps to install Skype:

```
sudo pacman -Syu yaourt
```

Yaourt allows you to install package from the AUR. The next step is then

```
yaourt -S skypeforlinux-stable-bin
```

Note that there are several AUR packages that have 'skype' in their name. The description for [skypeforlinux-stable-bin](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/skypeforlinux-stable-bin/) says

> Note that AUR package skypeforlinux-stable-bin is the version Microsoft release as their "stable" version. AUR package skypeforlinux-preview-bin is the version Microsoft release as their preview version and will always be a later version than the stable version. Please don't flag the stable version out of date because you find/read about the later preview version.